# upload a file in SAPUI5 and send to Gateway server

Tags: sapui5

I am having difficulties trying to figure out a way to send uploaded file and send it to a Gateway server. I am using the basic FileUploader control.

```
    ***<u:FileUploader
        id="fileUploader"
        name="myFileUpload"
        uploadUrl="upload/"
        width="400px"
        tooltip="Upload your file to the local server"
        uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete"/>
    <Button
        text="Upload File"
        press="handleUploadPress"/>***
```

And in the controller I have the following event handler

```
     ***handleUploadPress: function(oEvent) {
        var oFileUploader = this.getView().byId("fileUploader");
        oFileUploader.upload();
    }***
```

What code should I add after ***oFileUploader.upload()*** to have an xstring that I can pass to my attachment property of my OData srvice

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to do is to make sure that you have a gateway service that is able to handle media types and streams. To set this up you need to set the entity that is handling the file content as a media type and get the logic in place that deals with streams (CREATE_STREAM). You can find more information on how to do this in [this SCN blog](http://scn.sap.com/community/gateway/blog/2014/07/24/uploading-files-to-sap-gw-downloading-files-from-sap-gw--new-techniques).

In your UI5 application, you will have to set the URL of the upload control to e.g. `/sap/opu/odata/sap/AWESOME_SERVICE/Customers('0000123456')/$value` so that the file is handled by the CREATE_STREAM method that you just implemented.

When the upload is eventually taking place, you need to deal with two header parameters; the `slug` and the `CSRF token`. The slug header should be set to e.g. the filename, while the CSRF token needs to be retrieved using a pre-flight request. To set the headers, you could use something like this:

```
oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(new FileUploaderParameter({
    name: "x-csrf-token",
    value: _csrfToken
}));
```

The `slug` header parameter could be set in a similar way and should contain something that identifies the file, e.g. filename or id.

To determine the CSRF token, you could do something like this:

```
var _csrfToken = "";
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/sap/opu/odata/sap/AWESOME_SERVICE",
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-Token": "Fetch",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "DataServiceVersion": "2.0"
    },
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        _csrfToken = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('x-csrf-token');
    }
});
```

With the right header parameters in place, sending the file to a properly configured gateway entity should do the trick to get your file uploaded.

Comment: Excellent textbook explanation on OData Gateway file upload! Wish I had this clear explanation a while ago, would have saved me lots of wasted hours :)

Comment: Thanks Robin. Uploading is a bit painful and will remain that way I'm afraid. It's fortunate that Willard mentioned that he's using SAP Gateway as his backend. The solution might have needed to be quite different if you upload to e.g. Azure. It's fortunate that these controls offer a good amount of configurability so that you can deal with the quirks of backend systems. But this probably makes it more difficult for those who just start with this tech.

Comment: @jpenninkhof How would you incorporate the the upload of documents into a batch request

Comment: @willardChingarande I would prefer not to do that. Is there a specific reason why you would like to push it into a batch request?

Comment: @jpenninkhof not really. For knowledge purposes. So I am assuming that if you have a requirement to upload documents and you are also doing some operations not really related to uploads in the same app, you will then have two separate requests, one batch request for all other requests and one for the upload

Comment: @willardChingarande That's right. Batching is meant to combine several smaller type requests for performance reasons. An upload usually doesn't fall into that category and is best to be sent in parallel with other requests.